# How does a simple AC circuit radiate?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, electric-current, electronics

## Introduction

I'm sure a lot of us have seen the controversial video made by Veritasium:
[The Big Misconception About Electricity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY)

Now what I want to ask in this post is not to argue about any of the claims made during the video, as I am pretty sure he cleared a lot of them up in his follow-up video. No, what I want to ask is regarding his animation representing the electromagnetic fields around an ac circuit:

[image]

Now I am pretty sure everyone would agree that the entire field turning on and off in phase with the battery is obviously the wrong picture here since that would most definitely violate the second postulate of SR (which is literally built on electromagnetism).

We all know that the true picture is of the circuit radiating EM waves as the electric field of the battery oscillates like that of an oscillating dipole ([Oscillating Dipole by John Belcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rsu582YjEw)). Now my question is then **how exactly would the EM waves radiate and in what direction?**

The following sections are just me trying to answer the question myself but obviously failing but is optional in answering this question (everything you need to know to answer this question is all in this introduction). But if you want to know why I have been troubled by this question, feel free to continue reading:

## The Math

Now let me get into some maths first with the conservation of energy from the Poynting theorem. Now if we integrate over the entire space for the equation $\vec{J}\cdot\vec{E} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{S}$, we get:

$\frac{d}{dt}(E_{Mechanical} + E_{Field}) = 0$

Where $E_{Mechanical}$ is contributed by work done by the field on charges ($\vec{J}\cdot\vec{E}$, i.e. energy dissipated in the resistor: $I^2 R$), and $E_{Field} = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}} (\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}|\vec{E}|^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}|\vec{B}|^2)dV$ is the energy stored in the field, or more accurately, the potential energy of the system.

We are also missing one more term: $E_{Chemical}$ or $E_{Battery}$, which is the mysterious energy source that keeps replenishing the dipole of the battery, and so the full equation becomes:

$\frac{d}{dt}(-E_{Battery} - E_{Mechanical}) = \frac{d}{dt}E_{Field}$

## Proposals

To make this simple, let us make a few assumptions first:

1. The battery and the resistor are perfect dipoles (i.e. d -> 0)
2. Surface charges can instantaneously rearrange themselves

Now here are a few proposals with some reasoning as to why I think they might be false:

### Direction of Travel

#### 1. Radially:

This may first seem reasonable as it simply just uses the principle of relativity to assume information (i.e. the battery oscillating) travels at the speed of light.

But then it can be realised that this propagating electromagnetic field can also influence the surface charges all along the wire of the circuit, which then themselves will also create its own "sphere of influence" (pun intended) propagating outwards at the speed of light, which then refutes this proposal.

In addition to that, the energy from the battery should all really be transferred to the battery, not to infinity.

#### 2. Along Poynting vectors in the dc version of the circuit:

Now this would definitely seem very plausible at first, as it makes sense that the waves should all be propagating from the battery toward the resistor to transfer all its energy.

Yet the problem comes from the math of the problem:

$\frac{d}{dt}(-E_{Battery} - E_{Mechanical}) = \frac{d}{dt}E_{Field}$

Now from simple circuit analysis, we know that $E_{Battery} = -IV$, while $E_{Mechanical} = I^2 R$, resulting in:

$\frac{d}{dt}(IV - I^2 R) = \frac{d}{dt}E_{Field}$

Now usually, we can just say $IV - I^2 R = 0$, but that's only true because the speed of light is very fast for any normal circuit, and since we're doing physics, we can imagine a really long circuit, now the first problem presents itself:

Now if we agree with our proposal that the waves propagate along the Poynting vectors, this would result in multiple paths for the electromagnetic field to be "updated". But each of these paths has different lengths and so what exactly would be the electric field at the resistor, or more importantly, what is the time delay between $IV$ and $I^2 R$?

Even if we assume that the time delay is the time taken for information to travel in the shortest path (i.e. the straight line from the battery to the resistor), and take the length of the circuit to be $c/f$ ($f$ is the frequency of oscillation of the voltage), we will get $IV - I^2 R = 0$ as the phase difference at the battery and the resistor is $2π$, and so now we have:

$\frac{d}{dt}E_{Field} = 0$

But again, if we consider the multiple paths the EM waves take again, they are all out of phase with the shortest path and so will not result in a constant $E_{Field}$, contradicting the above equation.

### How it Travels

#### 1. The same field as a dc circuit but oscillating in magnitude spatially:

Although this is the basis of how transmission lines work, it just always seems so hand-wavy. Now although not a sound argument, I always imagined the propagation of an EM wave to be a complicated intermediate region between the new and old field ([Decreasing Dipole by John Belcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nIPqudCh9o)) and so should be more complicated than just some form of variation of the "static/dc case".

---

Hopefully, someone can perhaps **provide me with a simple animation of how an AC circuit actually radiates and clear my confusion regarding this problem.**

Comment: You are trying to ask for the transient behaviour before the steady state of the DC flow comes about. Either you model the actual circuit to absurd levels of precision and accuracy, or you accept the patchwork of approximate stuff that can give a qualitative understanding. And in the AC case there must be energy being lost towards infinity. AC circuits can never be 100% efficient because they are radiating antennas. DC can at least point out that the fields can essentially be time-independent.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I mean yes it's like almost impossible to model even the simpliest circuit (I mean even for like a straight wire with a voltage applied across it you'd have to solve an impossible integral equation to find its surface charge distribution), but are you telling me that there's absolutely no way to visualise how an AC circuit would transmit its energy to a resistor or lose its energy? I mean the electromagnetic field of a DC circuit isn't that well known too but we can still approximately predict its behaviour.

Comment: FYI: [The Principle of Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity) states that the laws of physics should be the same for everyone, everywhere. It says nothing about a universal speed limit (a.k.a., "speed of light.") Einstein's _Theory_ of Relativity was so-named because it rescues the Principle of Relativity from contradictions between [Maxwell's theory of electromagnetic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Maxwell's_equations) and older ideas about how we should understand basic stuff like space and time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yep sorry, I basically just meant the second postulate of SR

Comment: I'm not going to try to plow through all your math.  Had you stopped before you proposed a solution then I could help you with the simple observation that a loop of wire, excited by a source, is an antenna.  It _has_ to couple your circuit to the aether (well, or **free space** if you want to be all 20th century about it).  So if it's a DC circuit _and_ you switch it on suddenly, the AC components from that switch-on transient will be radiated.  If it's an AC circuit and you excite it close to a resonance point of the antenna -- well, that's how you use bits of wire to transmit radio!

Comment: @TimWescott Yes I do know that it acts like an antenna, but my question is how it radiates, i.e. how would the electromagnetic field look like approximately and radiate is what direction.

Comment: It is an electric dipole radiation, and the intensity is maximum for directions belonging to a plane orthogonal to the plane of the circuit. It is zero for a vertical direction in the plane of the circuit. https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node95.html

Comment: An AC circuit radiates similar to an antenna https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253957/46708

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski I mean that only describes how the battery (modelled as an electric dipole) radiates, not how the entire circuit radiates, as there are surface charges which will rearrange themselves in the circuit and influence how the field behaves.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Yes I know the wires themselves act like an antenna but unlike a normal system with a transmitter and a receiver, there are wires that run parallel to the path between the battery (“transmitter”) and the resistor (“receiver”) , and I want to know how the surface charges on the wires affect the propagation of that EM wave, does it concentrate more energy to the resistor? Or does is not? How do the EM waves look like if we consider the effects of the surface charges on those wires?

Comment: This is StackExchange, where we want nice tidy question-answer pairs, **not** long discussion in the comments.  You keep putting up bits of "but what I'm really asking is..." in your comments.  Why don't you **edit your question** so that you're actually asking what you want to know.  At the same time, **remove the bits where you're guessing at an answer**, unless your question is specifically about why your guesses are or are not right.  When you have a question that is _answerable_, then you may actually get an answer.

Comment: @TimWescott I'm sorry, but my question has not changed from then til now, all I want to know is how the radiation propagates around a simple AC circuit, it's in the title, the last line of the introduction and the last line of my entire question. The thing is just that every "but what I'm really asking is..." is just me repeating the same question I've been asking the whole time to people saying the circuit is just like an antenna/electric dipole. Yes, that is absolutely correct if we are really far away from the circuit, but that's not exactly what I'm asking, is it?

Comment: And I wouldn't really call this a long discussion considering it really was just multiple QnAs stacked together rather than a constant back-and-forth between me and other people. (And honestly, I'm sure there are longer comment sections than this one on StackExchange)

Comment: As for the bits where I was guessing at an answer, I really don't believe that's the correct attitude in learning. Part of asking a question should also really be giving your own perspective on the question so that people can follow your thought process and understand why you have been struggling with this question. Sure, I can mark those parts as optional to read in order to answer my question, but I don't think I would be removing that part.